# Import single databases mysql file from command line

Tags: mysql, database, import

I am using XAMPP, but I needed a new PHP version, so I had to install the new XAMPP available. As I got many websites, it is very hard to export every single database and then to import it. That's why I have exported all databases in one single SQL file, which is big around 8 GB.

My question is how to import that big file from the command line, when it includes all my databases ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: try: mysql -h localhost -u username -p < filename.sql

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u {username} -p {databasename} < file_name.sql
```